# Tumblr post heading link to source and not permalink page

Tags: tumblr

I would like the headings of my posts to link directly to the original source of the post and not to the permalink page.

I noticed the theme variables `{Permalink}` or `{SourceURL}` in the HTML of the theme? Is this related?

Answer (score 1):

#### Reblog Links

Tumblr provides theme variables for handling *reblogged* posts.

First we need to determine if a post has been reblogged using `{block:RebloggedFrom}`. Then we can generate a link to it with `{ReblogRootURL}`.

We also need to provide a fall back, incase the post hasn't been reblogged using `{block:NotReblog}`.

**Example**

```
{block:Text}

<!-- Rendered if the post has been reblogged -->
{block:RebloggedFrom}
<h2>
  <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" target="_blank">{Title}</a>
</h2>
{/block:RebloggedFrom}

<!-- Rendered if the post has not been reblogged -->
{block:NotReblog}
<h2>
  <a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>
</h2>
{/block:NotReblog} 

{/block:Text}
```

**References**

- Reblogs: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#reblogs
- Text Posts: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#text-posts